# Using WebView Like this would work?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using drawables in src for  tag in webview would this work?

```
     mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("","<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td style=\"text-
     align:center; background-color:grey;\"><img src=\""+R.id.button+"\"/></td></tr>                
     </table>"+Question, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Comment: sir that really helped but it is working correctly on emulator but not on the device .Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using drawables in src for tag in webview would this work?

Absolutely not. HTML expects URLs for images. Not to mention that you are specifying a widget ID, not a drawable resource.

> sir that really helped but it is working correctly on emulator but not on the device .Do you know how to solve it?

Perhaps your device is older -- one answer on the question that Mr. Clayson linked to suggests that `file:///android_res/` URLs only work on Android 2.2 and higher.

However, the `android.resource` scheme has been around longer:

`android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]`

e.g.:

`android.resource://this.is.my.package/drawable/button`

I have not tried this in `WebView`, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Thanx,But Sir this also not working.

Comment: @Navdroid: Then using image resources in HTML may simply not be possible, at least on older versions of Android. You can move your images into `assets/` and use `file:///android_asset/` `Uri` values to reference them.